# Привязка PHP к Apache

Tags: php, apache, centos

Собственно вопрос в том, как включить поддержку PHP в Apache. Открыв localhost, браузер лишь предлагает сохранить index.php (index.html отображает корректно). Как сделать, что бы и PHP скрипты отображались?

Comment: Перезагрузитесь и все станет отлично.

Comment: Какая операционная система?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как нужен как модуль к апачу или как а-ля CGI?

```
LoadModule php5_module c:/php-5.3.5/php5apache2_2.dll  AddType application/x-httpd-php phtml php PHPIniDir "c:/php-5.3.5/"
```

Ну как-то так, это под виндой.

Под unix немного иначе но смысл такой же.

Но из вопроса непонятно какая Ось и какие ошибки выползают.

Answer (score 1):

Если CentOS (в теме есть тег), то в моём конфиге такое, конечно нужно установить php

```
# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf<IfModule prefork.c>  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so</IfModule><IfModule worker.c>  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so</IfModule>AddHandler php5-script .phpAddType text/html .phpDirectoryIndex index.php
```