# Браузер показывает php-код вместо результата его выполнения

Tags: php

Chrome код html читает. Но как начинается работа с php, браузер просто показывает скрипт, который я написал в редакторе. Я пытался ставить кавычки, " '", даже искал готовый вариант авторизации в интернете, но chrome просто показывает код программы. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: PHP выполняется на сервере специальным интерпретатором.  Вы его устанавливали и настраивать сервер?

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/34420/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/340891/178576), и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы работал PHP, нужно запустить локальный PHP-сервер, загрузить на него сайт, и заходить по ip этого сервера (*http://localhost в случае локального сервера*).

Это необходимо из за того, что вот HTML выполняется на стороне клиента (в браузере), а вот PHP команды обрабатываются на сервере, а в браузер отправляется уже готовый результат.

Проще всего запустить локальный сервер на Windows - установить XAMPP, запустить его, и в папку XAMPP/htdocs положить файлы сайта. И заходить после этого в браузере на http://localhost

*P.S.: Кстати в комплект XAMPP входит система управления базами данных MySQL, которая часто используется в связке с PHP для хранения различных данных сайта (к примеру таблица пользователей)*

*P.P.S.: XAMPP также может играть роль "боевого" сервера (можно разместить на нём реальный сайт(ы), привязать к нему домен и тд.) если [открыть порты](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%2080%20windows&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%2080%20windows&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.8830j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Тогда люди из интернета смогут зайти на него, вставив в адресную строку ваш IP (либо привязанный к нему домен)*

Удачи.

Comment: И, кстати, *проще всего* запустить сервер встроенный в РНР

Comment: Так же могу не могу не упомянуть [OpenServer](https://ospanel.io/) - отличный вариант для новичка

Answer (score 1):

Еще одной причиной может быть использование в коде которких РНР тегов, `<?`.

Для совместимости необходимо использовать полные теги, `<?php`

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень помогли. Пол часа провозился, прежде чем сюда зашёл)